# Estimate most probable (mode) value from samples of continuous variable in Python

Tags: python

There is an array of samples from a **continuous** random variable. How can I (easily) get an estimation of the most probable value (the mode) using Python? Ideal it would be something like `numpy.mpv(samples)`.

Comment: Find the modes of the density estimators of largest samples.

Comment: I think you are getting votes to close because you seem to be asking specifically for Python code rather than a general method.

Comment: I am with @BruceET. Questions about particular software implementations are off-topic. However, you seem have a statistics question hidden in here that asks about estimating the mode. Perhaps you can edit your post to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

In R, I generated a sample of size $n=1000$ from
the distribution $\mathsf{Gamma}(\mathrm{shape}=7,\mathrm{rate}=.1),$
which has mode $60.$

Now suppose you don't know the distribution family from which the
sample was taken. Then you might approximate the population
mode roughly by taking the midpoint of the tallest bar of a histogram
of the sample with suitably many bins. More precisely, you could
find the mode of a density estimator of the population, based
on the sample.

In R, you could use the default density estimator, which
gives 512 $(x,y)$ pairs, estimating the density of
a sample. Then do a grid search for the x-value that
maximizes the y-value of the density estimator. In the
example below this method estimates the population mode as 60.6.

```
set.seed(2021)
x = rgamma(1000, 7, .1)
den.est = density(x)
mean(den.est$x[den.est$y==max(den.est$y)])
[1] 60.63108
```

The figure below shows a histogram of the data along with
the density estimator (red) and the population density (blue),
which would be unknown in an actual application.

[image]

```
hdr = "Histogram of 1000 Obs. with Density Estimator (red)"
hist(x, prob=T, ylim=c(0,.018), col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
 lines(density(x), lwd=2, col="red")
 curve(dgamma(x,7,.1), add=T, col="blue")
```

*Notes on other methods:* (1) If you *do* know the distribution family, it may be better to
use sufficient statistics to estimate the parameters, and use
them to find the mode.

(2) If you happen to draw just the right histogram, you can do pretty well by taking the mode to be at the middle of the bin with the tallest bar:

```
hist(x, prob=T, br=seq(10,200, by=10), col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

(3) If a boxplot of the data shows a moderately right-skewed distribution, then it is likely the distribution will have mode < median < mean. Then sample mean and median may help make a
useful estimate of the population mode.

```
mean(x); median(x)
[1] 70.02557  # population mean 70
[1] 65.43304  
qgamma(.5, 7, .1)
[1] 66.69637  # population median
# true population mode is 60; density estimator 60.6
```

Comment: This is a good answer (+1), but the core idea is delayed until the the fourth paragraph. Maybe it would be better to open the answer with "If the distribution family of your sample is unknown, use a density estimator".

Comment: Thanks. Actually mentioned density estimation in 2nd paragraph. My initial comment right below the question was mean to focus on density estimate from the start. // Moved non-density methods to note at end.